# "This past weekend", "last weekend, or "this weekend" in context?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say today is Monday, February the second and I want to say that I did something on Sunday, February the first. Does the following sentences all mean the same?

> I cleaned my house **last weekend**.
>
> I cleaned my house **this weekend**.
>
> I cleaned my house **this past weekend**.

I aksed a similar question, except it was about the use of the phrases with *night*. And I was told that *this past* night doesn't sound as natural. What about *weekend*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I cleaned my house *this weekend*" is incorrect - as *this weekend* refers to the upcoming weekend. You can't have cleaned (in the past tense) in the future. You could say "*I will clean my house this weekend*".

Apparently, "this past weekend" is used, but far, far less than "last weekend", as evidenced by [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=last%20weekend%2Cthis%20past%20weekend&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clast%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20past%20weekend%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Personally, if it's only Monday I would probably say _at the weekend_. I would only use _last_ when the end of the current week is approaching.

Comment: @KateBunting but you'd need to use tense to specify which. If you meant *last weekend*, you'd say "cleaned". But if you said "I *will clean* my house at the weekend", that's the future. Further, if you said "I clean my house at the weekend" that means *every* weekend.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the question was about the past tense.

Comment: @KateBunting Not just the past - the most recent weekend. I understand he's looking for idiomatic ways to refer to "last weekend". You could refer to any weekend in the past using "at the weekend".

Comment: @KateBunting - I agree with your first comment, but for one thing: wouldn't you say "on" the weekend?  E.g. "I went to the beach on the weekend." or "I cleaned my house on the weekend."  I've lived & worked in Australia, the UK and Europe, and "at" the weekend sounds really odd to me!  :)

Comment: @TechnoCat No, _at_ the weekend is standard British English. I know Americans use _on_, but that sounds really odd to me!

Comment: @Astralbee On a Monday or Tuesday I would probably speak of what I did 'at the weekend'. Later in the week it would be 'last weekend'. Further back, 'the weekend before last', 'the first weekend in January' etc. I wouldn't use 'at the weekend' of 'any weekend in the past' unless I had been describing events during that whole week.

Comment: If it is Sunday and you did something on Saturday, you can't refer to it as "I did it this weekend?" You would have to say "yesterday" or "on Saturday"?

Comment: @KateBunting - Until reading this question & the ensuing dialogue, I'd never taken notice of the phrase and never noticed the British difference (even when living & in Britain).  I see this page - https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/at-the-weekend-or-on-the-weekend/ - discusses the differences.  I'll now start taking careful note of what others say!  :)

Comment: @anouk Sunday is part of the weekend, so, yes, you could say that something you did the day before happened 'this weekend'. The conversation was about expressions used on a weekday.

Comment: "Marian Mursult was three days gone, last seen this past Friday; Monday morning would dawn in just a few hours."